# finding the theoretical speed based on current speed

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, word-problem

A bird is attempting to fly northeast at a constant speed, but a wind blowing southward at 5 miles per hour blows the bird off course. If the bird’s overall movement (incorporating its intended movement and the movement due to wind) is at a $\sqrt{53}$ miles per hour, how fast would it have been traveling if there was no wind?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the bird's intended movement is $x$ mph north and $x$ mph east at once, so $\sqrt2x$ mph northeast in total. The wind means that the bird is actually travelling $x-5$ mph north, so by the Pythagorean theorem we have $x^2+(x-5)^2=53$ or $x=7$. So the bird's speed without wind is $7\sqrt2$ mph.

Comment: thanks! everything you said made sense, but why are we assuming that its speed north is the same as the east one?

Comment: @cheesecake it is flying due northeast, so $45^\circ$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\vec{v}_{bird} = v_{bird}\cos\pars{\pi \over 4}\hat{x}+
v_{bird}\sin\pars{\pi \over 4}\hat{y}\quad\pars{~\color{red}{without}\
\mbox{ wind}~}
\\[5mm]
&\vec{v}_{bird+} = v_{bird}\cos\pars{\pi \over 4}\hat{x} +
\bracks{v_{bird}\sin\pars{\pi \over 4} - 5}\hat{y}\quad\pars{~\color{red}{with}\
\mbox{wind}~}
\\[5mm]
& 53 = v_{bird+} =
\left.\root{{v_{bird}^{2} \over 2} + \pars{{v_{bird} \over \root{2}} - 5}^{2}}
\right\vert_{\large\ v_{bird}\ \geq\ 0}
&\\[5mm] \implies &
\bbx{v_{bird} = 7\root{2}\ {\mrm{m} \over \mrm{h}}
\approx 9.8995\ {\mrm{m} \over \mrm{h}}}\\ &
\end{align}